# Problem with side menu - only on IPhone 5s

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile

Hello fellow developers! 
First cry for help here.

I am encountering a strange error with my website when displaying it on IPhone 5s. 
I have a mobile side-menu that is positioned absolute and has a z-index of 1000. 
It is sliding from the left on the screen when user clicks a hamburger menu icon. 
It is working perfectly on desktop, IPad and on Huawei mobile, but on my IPhone 5s it looks like this: 
[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBlzm.jpg)
[Section page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owZ6n.png)[Correct version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm8Fw.png)

Seems like it covers the header, but fails to overlay the main section. 
This is how the element is styled:

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: 300ms;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
```

Here's a link to my website's github repo: https://github.com/djlens/Maciek-Martyka-website/tree/master/website

Thanks in advance, I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: I had faced this issue once. As far as I can remember, you will have to explicitly provide the height for the container in your absolutely positioned side-menu. Try `min-height: 100vh`.

Comment: @Sterex hasn't worked :/ 
To be completely clear I had it work properly before commiting some changes and now I can't figure out what is the issue... 
I've uploaded css code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

If someone was struggling with the same issue...

I had to move the whole side menu div section out of HTML traditional flow. Before it was contained in the `<header>` section which apparently caused it to interfere with `<main>` content. Then I moved it to `<main>` and then it overlayed with `<header>` content. Eventually what fixed the bug was removing it completely out of the flow and placing it inbetween the `<header>` and the `<main>`. Side menu is positioned absolute.

This was IPhone 5s specific issue and above solution fixed it. There were no problems id displaying the site on more modern devices like IPhone 6 or IPad.